# Gnuplot: Keybinding not working

Tags: bash, loops, gnuplot, exit, key-bindings

I have a bash script that calls a gnu plot script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm plot.dat

writedata() {
for i in {1..10}; do

    cat << EOF > plot.dat
    $i #there is more here but it doesn't matter
    EOF
    sleep 1
    done
}
writedata &
sleep 1
gnuplot -persist liveplot.gnu
```

Here is liveplot.gnu:

```
ext = 0
bind all q 'ext = 1'
load 'loop.gnu'
```

and here is loop.gnu

```
while(!ext) {

 set xrange [0:6]
 set yrange [0:6]
 set cbrange [0:10]
 unset key
 set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)
 set view map

 set pm3d interpolate 15,15

 splot "plot.dat" matrix with pm3d
 pause 1
}
```

However, it does not work as intended. What I need is for the loop to continue until the user presses the "q" Button. But this way it runs forever and I need to kill the bash script to stop the loop. 
If I call

```
bind q
```

it shows me

```
q            * `ext = 1'
```

which seems right to me. However, if I print ext, it is always 0.

What do I need to change here? I tried various other ways with reread etc, but could not get it to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Works fine for me using gnuplot 5 and the qt terminal. Which version and terminal do you use? That could also depend on your window manager.

Comment: I'm using Gnuplot 4.6 and wxt terminal. I also noticed that the coordinate display on the bottom left is constant (probably initial mouse position) even if I move my mouse.

Comment: Did you try by binding another key? I get the same behavior you report, terminal independent with gnuplot 5, but it is solved when I try `set bind all p 'ext=1'`

Comment: Also, in my case, `help bind` mentions that "A user-specified binding supersedes any builtin bindings, except that <space> and 'q' cannot normally be rebound."

Comment: I tried it using w, and now p like your suggestion, but it does not help.

Comment: Same here, no keybindings work - Ubuntu 18.04, gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2, set terminal wxt, just trying from 'help bind' the `bind "ctrl-alt-a" 'print "great"'` and it never triggers. EDIT: just realized, it does trigger for x11 terminal, just not wxt...